# Timing commands in Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal

I would like to time the execution time of a commited Metal command buffer.
However I need more finegrained timing information for each of the commands in the queue and I dont know how to get this information out.

Is there a way to discover the length of time each enqueued command takes when running a Metal command queue?

A simple brute force way to do so would be to sequentially load up each command, run the buffer, find the time up to that point, rerun but with an extra command and continue in this way until I have a cumulative array of values and then just find the difference of each. However this feels very hacky for something which might potentially be easy and I just cannot find the function call.

Comment: your best tool is Metal System Trace which gives you granular access to command buffers. I recommend watching the last part of the 604 session from WWDC 2016.

Comment: Metal doesn't currently offer API for getting timing information programmatically at a granularity finer than command buffers. However, if you take a GPU Frame Capture while debugging your app, you can view the duration of each draw call. Metal System Trace is a good way to get a more global view of your app's behavior (including buffer execution duration) over time.